# Crosstabs includes missing values

Tags: missing-data, spss, crosstab

When I make a cross tab (using SPSS version 22), my missing values are included (see image below). This is something I do not want. If anyone could tell me how I could exclude the missing values that would be great :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: It looks like your variable como_af is a string. String variables do not have missing values, they just have blanks. You might want to consider recoding it into a numeric variable for easier analysis:

```
if como_af = "Yes" como_af_num = 1. 
if como_af = "No" como_af_num = 2. 
if como_af = "" como_af_num = $sysmis.
```

or alternatively:

```
recode como_af ("Yes"=1) ("No"=2) (""=sysmis) into como_af_num.
```

now if you cross nihss_mild by como_af_num, the blanks (now sysmis) will be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin mentioned, you need to set your user-missing values.

I'll just mention that for String variables (such as in your case), system-missing values (blanks) are not considered missing by default.  If your variable were Numeric, blanks **would** automatically be considered missing.

To set empty values in a String variable to missing you can use:

```
MISSING VALUES comor_AF (" ") .
```

*Edit: Martin's updated solution does the trick too.*

Comment: Didnt know that blanks could be set to missing. Always just assumed that strings just couldnt have missing values. Thanks!